# TA-Lib : Technical Analysis Library, Lookback and unstablePeriod

Tags: c#, ta-lib, technical-indicator

TA-Lib is a financial/market/OHLC technical analysis library for a Java, C++, .Net, etc. In it are ~158 Technical Functions (EMA, MAMA, MACD, SMA, etc), each has an associate Lookback Function

```
public static int EmaLookback(int optInTimePeriod)
```

The Lookback for each function seems to return the minimum length of processing required to compute each function accurately. With the startIdx to the endIdx equal to the Lookback.

```
Core.RetCode retcode = Core.Ema(startIdx, endIdx, double inReal, optInTimePeriod, ref outBegIdx, ref outNBElement, double outReal)
```

Some of these functions use an array called

```
Globals.unstablePeriod[0x17]
```

If this is incorrect in any way please correct me. Now the questions ...

1. The array unstablePeriod[] initializes to 0 for all entries. Is this what is supposed to occur, if not where in TA-Lib do I find the code or data that it is initialized with?
2. The code we are writing only requires the single most recent element in the array outReal[0] (or any other "outArray[]"). Is there a way to return a single element(a), or does the the spread between the startIdx and the endIdx have to equal the Lookback(b)?

a)

```
int startIdx = this.ohlcArray.IdxCurrent;
int endIdx = startIdx; 
// call to TA Routine goes here
```

b)

```
int lookBack = Core.EmaLookback(optInTimePeriod) - 1;
int startIdx = this.ohlcArray.IdxCurrent;
int endIdx = startIdx + lookBack;
// call to TA Routine goes here
retcode = Core.Ema(startIdx, endIdx, inReal, optInTimePeriod, ref outBegIdx, ref outNBElement, outReal);
```

3. Why is do these routines return 0, for the first outArray[0] element, when startIdx is equal to 0?
4. Since I am getting such odd results. Should the startIdx be at the oldest date or the newest date? Meaning should you process from the past (startIdx) towards now (endIdx), or from now (startIdx) towards the oldest date(endIdx) in time? I am guessing I am computing backwards (b)

   a) 2000 (startIdx) - 2003 (endIdx), 

   or
    
   b) 2003 (startIdx) - 2000 (endIdx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already forget C# so might be wrong, but:

> The Lookback for each function seems to return the minimum length of processing required to compute each function accurately. With the startIdx to the endIdx equal to the Lookback.

No, it returns number of input elements that required to calculate first output element. Which is usually equal or more than timePeriod value. That's all. So if you input 1000 elements (StartIdx == 0 and endIdx == 9999) while Lookback function gives you 25 you'll get 1000-25 = 9975 == outNBElement resulting elements back. And outBegIdx will be 24.
Note: noone guarantees accuracy of function. Lookback just let you calculate size of resulting array beforehand which is critical for C/C++ where fixed size arrays might be allocated.

> The array unstablePeriod[] initializes to 0 for all entries. Is this what is supposed to occur, if not where in TA-Lib do I find the code or data that it is initialized with?

Seems like that. It happens in Core::GlobalsType constructor in TA-Lib-Core.h

Globals.unstablePeriod is an array that keeps unstability settings for some of TA funcs. The values addressed via `enum class FuncUnstId` which is declared in `ta_defs.h`. The 0x17 value would correspond to T3 technical indicator.

In case of T3 indicator this unstability period just adds a value to lookback result. So T3's lookback is `6 * (timePeriod-1) + TA_GLOBALS_UNSTABLE_PERIOD[TA_FUNC_UNST_T3]`. That's why it's 0 by default. And that's clear that function accuracy isn't that simple.

Consider EMA. Its lookback is `timePeriod-1 + TA_GLOBALS_UNSTABLE_PERIOD[TA_FUNC_UNST_EMA]`. Assume unstability value is 0. So EMA is only a timePeriod-1. (I would recommend do not touch unstability without a reason). According to the code I see - its first EMA result is calculated as simple average of a first "lookback count" of elements by default. There is a global compatibility setting that might be {CLASSIC, METASTOCK, TRADESTATION} and affects first element calculation, but this doesn't change a lot. Your first element is an average and others are calculated as EMA_today = `(value_today - old_EMA)*coefficient + old_EMA`.

That's the reason you can't just pass "lookback count" of elements and get "accurate function result". It won't be accurate - it'll be the first one, not the right one. In case of EMA it'll always be a simple average as simple average is used as a seed for this function. And following results are calculated not only over first N input elements but include previous EMA value. And this previous EMA includes its previous EMA etc. So you can't just pass lookback count of elements and expect the accurate result. You would need to pass previous function value too.
Moreover, most rolling indicators behave like that. Their first N values are heavily depend on point from which you'd started to calculate them. This might be addressed with Unstability period but you'd better to not limit the input data.

> Why is do these routines return 0, for the first outArray[0] element
>   My guess it's bcs of -1 in your lookback calculation. Also 0 is returned for outBegIdx'th element, not the 0 element.
>
> Is there a way to return a single element(a)

With regular TA-Lib - no, or you need to process big enough piece of data every time to make sure your rolling results do "converge". But I've made a TA-Lib fork for myself [here](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt) which is designed for this purpose. The main idea is described in readme. It should be almost as fast as original and you can just pass single value and state object to get single result back without recalculation of all data. So calculation might be paused and continued when new data arrives without loss of previous computational results.
The problem is that TA-Lib is written in C and code of all its C#/Java etc wrappers are actually generated by its internal tool (ta-gen). No one ever tried to work with my fork via those wrapper interfaces. So they may be broken. Also i don't provide precompiled binaries and as TA-Lib is very old and its infrastructure is quite fancy it might require some skill and efforts to build it on target platform

Comment: There is more information in this one response than I have been able to find searching for the past couple weeks. If you are interested in a C# version of TA-Lib I did one using dot net reflector a couple years back [link](https://github.com/DavidFuchs42/TALibraryInCSharp). I have one more question. Edited and added it above also. Because of the odd results I have been getting, **should the startIdx be at the oldest date or the newest date?** Meaning should you process from the past forward, or from now back in time?

Comment: @DavidCFuchs startIdx should point to the oldest date. So it's option a)

Comment: I began reworking the data engine last night, when I figured that out.

Comment: The initialization period for indicators that use smoothing can be much longer than you think.  I've actually [done some analysis](https://github.com/DaveSkender/Stock.Indicators/discussions/215#discussioncomment-179106) on this to demonstrate how smoothing impacts RSI values, as an example.  For EMA, it can be up to 200+ bars beyond the lookback period before you get accuracy to two decimal points.  Like you, I've struggled with TA-Lib, despite using it for a decade.  Instead of reworking TA-Lib, try a more modern library: [Stock.Indicators](https://daveskender.github.io/Stock.Indicators).